# Javascript (node.js): Iterating through nested objects and getting undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, object, nested

*I am running this code using node on the command line. My current issue right now is that the line **console.log(checkparam[key].stat);** is returning undefined rather than a value.*

In the following code I am trying to display all the values for a set of properties within an object that is nested within another object. The problem is that I am getting undefined because the "stat" var is being recognized by javascript as a literal stat property in the lower nested object rather than as the value of the stat as it should be in the for(var stat in checkparam[key]) loop.

```
var viewSheet = function(name, checkparam) {
for(var key in checkparam) {
    if(checkparam[key].playerFirstName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
        for(var stat in checkparam[key])
        {
                console.log(checkparam[key].stat);
        }
        //return checkparam[key];
    }
}
```

};
I know that the stat in the for loop mentioned above is correctly pointing to the property KEY in the lower nested object because I can just console.log those fine and they display the key values. I just don't understand what the correct process is to get Javascript to recognize that I want to log that specific value.

Also I know questions on stack should be based on single specific problems, but if anyone is willing to also answer a second question, am I using objects incorrectly here? The way javascript objects are seems to me just like python dictionaries or perl hashes and therefor I keep thinking it's ok to nest data in the same way as I would in those languages.

Here is the entire piece of the code for context.

```
//--MODULES

//Readline Sync for CLI prompting
var rlprompt = require('readline-sync');

//--DECLARE OBJECTS //
var fverparty = new Object();

//--DEFINE FUNCS //

//LIST FUNCTION
var list = function (param) {
    console.log("Party members: ")
    for (var key in param) {
        console.log(param[key].playerFirstName);
    }
}

//ADD FUNCTION
var add = function (playerFirstName, list, playerLastName, playerRace, playerClass) {
    list[playerFirstName] = {
        playerFirstName: playerFirstName,
        playerLastName: playerLastName,
        playerRace: playerRace,
        playerClass: [playerClass]
    };
}

//VIEW FUNCTION
var viewSheet = function(name, checkparam) {
    for(var key in checkparam) {
        if(checkparam[key].playerFirstName.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {
            for(var stat in checkparam[key])
            {
                    console.log(checkparam[key].stat);
            }
            //return checkparam[key];
        }
    }
};


//--MAIN //

//-init 
var adding = true;

//-run

//Add characters to party.
console.log("Let's add some people to a list.")
while (adding){

    add(rlprompt.question("Please enter a first name: "), fverparty, rlprompt.question("Please enter a last name: "), rlprompt.question("Please enter a race: "), rlprompt.question("Please enter a class: "));
    if (rlprompt.question("Any key to continue, (q/Q) to quit.").toLowerCase() == "q") {
        adding = false;
    }
}

//List the party members
list(fverparty);

//View character sheets
viewSheet(rlprompt.question("Enter a name to view their character sheet: "), fverparty);
```

Comment: use stat like you are using key: `checkparam[key][stat]`

Comment: And that worked... I feel so dumb. Thank you very much @PatrickEvans. A followup question, what is the difference between checkparam.key.stat vs checkparam[key][stat] in the context of that for loop? IE i can console.log the first version but not the second if just bare but I can only console.log the second version and not first if inside the for loop?

Comment: If you have `var key="foo", stat="bar"`,
and you do `checkparam[key][stat]`, it will actually look for `checkparam.foo.bar`.
However `checkparam.key.stat` will *always* just look for `checkparam.key.stat`.

Comment: @laggingreflex ah interesting I get it, so the []'s indicate that the VALUES associated with key and stat need to be looked for while the foo.bar.stuff is always taken literally?

Comment: yep. more info: [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)